# How can I set ConfigurationBuilder to look at Azure App Server & Key Vault too?

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

The following works to get configuration settings from the appSettings files:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddUserSecrets(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
Configuration = builder.Build();
```

But how do I get it to also read from the Azure App Server configuration (including connection strings) and the Azure Key Vault?

There is an `AddAzureKeyVault()` but it needs the key vault credentials which wrecks the whole idea of the key vault not having it's credentials anywhere. And I can't find anything about the Azure App Server.

Also, do I have them added in the right order so it starts with the secrets file (last added)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you could refer to [Tutorial: Use Key Vault references in an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x#update-your-code-to-use-a-key-vault-reference).

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
{
    options.Connect(
        builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"])
            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
            {
                kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            });
});
```

And before you implement Key Vault references in your code,  be sure finish [Create an ASP.NET Core app with App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core6x) first.

Comment: Can you also add how to get the config settings in Azure App Service? I read the link and it talked about using the App Service config settings, but did not say how to includ them in the ConfigurationBuilder. TIA

Comment: Hi @DavidThielen, did you also read the second article I shared?